# Excel extract unique objects from list

Tags: excel

I have a large list of companies who collaborate with my company. My company is broken down into different research groups. A company might collaborate with a single research group multiple times on the list or with multiple research groups.

I would like to find out which companies only collaborate with a single research group. Example of data is below, you can see that company A only collaborates with group 1 but multiple times, but company B collabs with many groups. How can I count this?

Examples data:

`Group  Company
1         A
1         B
1         C
1         A
1         C
2         D
2         D
2         E
2         E
2         B
2         D
3         D
3         F
3         B
3         F
4         G
4         B
4         B`

It would be a binary result, 1=company is unique to group, 0=company is not unique to group.

An extension to this (although not included in my question) would be, how many groups do companies collab with on average

Comment: Can you give us an idea of how you would like the results to work?

A if(countif(xyz)=1,true,false) etc will work... just need a little bit more information on how to show it

Comment: @BryanDavies It would be a binary result, 1=company is unique to group, 0=company is not unique to group.

An extension to this (although not included in my question) would be, how many groups do companies collab with on average

Comment: I'd try a Pivot Table:

http://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/pivot-tables.html

But I don't know enough to help you. Sorry :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a workaround for what you want to achieve. Following solution use couple of helper columns and at the end will give result whether company is unique to group or not and count of groups companies collaborate with.

Assuming your data `Group` and `Company` are in `Column A` and `Column B` respectively follow the following steps:

***Step 1:*** **Get unique combination of Group and Company**

In `Cell D2` enter the following formula and drag/copy down as required.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$19 & "," & $B$2:$B$19,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($D$1:D1,$A$2:$A$19 &  "," & $B$2:$B$19),0,0),0)),"")
```

***Step 2:*** **Get count of each combination in data**

In `Cell E2` enter the following formula and drag/copy down till the row where `Column D` display values.

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$19,LEFT(D2,(FIND(",",D2,1)-1)),$B$2:$B$19,MID(D2,FIND(",",D2)+1,256))
```

This formula will give the count of occurrence of each combination from `Column D` in your data. For example, *Group 1* and *Company A* occurs two time in you data, *Group 2* and *Company D* occurs 3 times in your data, and so on.

***Step 3:*** **Get list of unique companies from `Column B`**

In `Cell F2` enter the following formula and drag/copy down as required.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$14,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($F$1:F1,$B$2:$B$14),0,0),0)),"")
```

***Step 4:*** **Get count of groups each company collaborate with**

In `Cell G2` enter the following formula and drag/copy down till the row where `Column F` display values.

```
=COUNT(IF(MID($D$2:$D$12,FIND(",",$D$2:$D$12)+1,256)=F2,$E$2:$E$12))
```

This is an array formula so commit it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

***Step 5:*** **Check whether company is unique to Group or not**

In `Cell H2` enter the following formula and drag/copy down till the row where `Column G` display values.

```
=IF(COUNT(IF(MID($D$2:$D$12,FIND(",",$D$2:$D$12)+1,256)=F2,$E$2:$E$12))=1,1,0)
```

Again, this is an array formula so commit it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

or instead use this formula `=IF(G2=1,1,0)`

[image]

---

**EDIT :** As per requirement mentioned in comment

In `Cell J2` enter:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$19 & "," & $A$2:$A$19,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($D$1:J1,$A$2:$A$19 &  "," & $B$2:$B$19),0,0),0)),"")
```

In `Cell K2` enter:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$19,MID(J2,FIND(",",J2)+1,256),$B$2:$B$19,LEFT(J2,(FIND(",",J2,1)-1)))
```

In `Cell L2` enter:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$19,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($L$1:L1,$A$2:$A$19),0,0),0)),"")
```

In `Cell M2` enter:

```
=COUNT(IF(VALUE(MID($J$2:$J$12,FIND(",",$J$2:$J$12)+1,256))=L2,$E$2:$E$12))
```

This is an array formula.

In `Cell N2` enter:

```
=IF(N2=1,1,0)
```

or

```
=IF(COUNT(IF(VALUE(MID($J$2:$J$12,FIND(",",$J$2:$J$12)+1,256))=L2,$E$2:$E$12))=1,1,0)
```

This formula is also an array formula.

See image for reference:

[image]

Comment: This is great, thanks! How would I then go onto make a list of number of unique companies per group?

Comment: @AlexH - Can you give more detail on what exactly you want in result?

Comment: Group 1 has 1 company unique to it, group 2 has no companies unique to it, etc @Mrig

Comment: @AlexH - But Group 1 do not have unique companies, it has 3 companies (A,B,C).

Comment: Thanks for your help, sorry to be a pain. Group 1 has 3 companies with it but company B also works with group 2 and 3 so is not unique to group 1. It has 2 unique companies as A and C do not work with any other groups @Mrig